# skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform, dstination points in example

Tags: python, scikit-image, affinetransform

In the [skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_piecewise_affine.html), blue points come from `tform.inverse()`, from this line:

```
ax.plot(tform.inverse(src)[:, 0], tform.inverse(src)[:, 1], '.b')
```

I draw destination points in red, It looks like this :
[output image with inversed points in blue, and destination points in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiaSk.png).

I have two questions about `skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform`.

1. Destination points (red points) and output image is not coherent. Suppose the image and inversed points are changed by `sin()` waves. But the destination points are changed by `1-sin()`. So what's the meaning of destination points?
2. What is `tform.inverse()`? I looked up, and annotation says it apply inverse transformation.
   But Why the inverse transformation isn't between destination points(red points) and source points(source mesh)?

In my view, mesh warp works like this (image from google) : [mesh warp example from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4omPc.png).
The man in the image should be warped follow the twisted mesh, which is the destination mesh. But the image in the astronaut example seems opposite from destination points.

In other words, I think blue points in the the astronaut image should be destination points instead of inverse transformation.

Thanks for all of you.
Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: The warp function expects the inverse coordinate map of the image transformation it applies. Hence, warp applies the transformation corresponding to the mapping of dst to src. I am not sure why warp requires the inverse map, that does seem slightly counterintuitive.

Comment: @JacobMadsen Thank you for your answer. It's really counterintuitive, I have found solution to map src to dst. Change `tform.estimate(src, dst)` to `tform.estimate(dst, src)`.